# Complexity of in-dominating set

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-domination

Is the decision problem *In-Dominating Set* NP-complete for digraphs of regular out-degree (greater than $\frac{n-2}{4}$, in particular)? --
I'm mainly looking for a reference.

Thanks for any answer!